# Bind an AutoCompleteTextView to an Array of Objects (ID,NAME)

Tags: c#, android, object, xamarin, autocompletetextview

I've been trying for a while to create an AutoCompleteTextView where you can search for a name, when you select a name from the list the controller should store somewhere (in my test it would be fine to just `Toast.MakeTest().Show()` the result).

**Here's my code:**

```
List<Persona> personeList = getPersone ();

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MyFragment, container, false);

        var autoCompleteSearchName = view.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView> (Resource.Id.autoTextName);

        ArrayAdapter<Persona> autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Persona> (
            view.Context, 
            Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, 
            personeList
        );

        autoCompleteSearchName.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;
```

This is the part where I bind the xml element to the controller, then I create the Adapter (Persona is an Object with properties int id and String name, exposing a ToString() method).

It works fine, I can start writing a letter and it shows the suggested names.

Now I would like to get the property id bound to the name that the user selects.
Is it possible?
The only alternative I know is using spinners, but I would like to show thousands of names so I would avoid the spinner if I can.

If you see any other solution I would really appreciate since I'm quite new to Xamarin.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT. I added the `autoCompleteSearchName.ItemClick += autoTextViewItemClick;`

This triggers when I select an option, the problem is that `e.Position` is relative to the display order, and is not bound in any way to my real Object,'s properties.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom adapter and use `e.Id` instead of `e.Position`. Don't forget to implement `Filter` in you adapter.

Note: you won't be able to subclass `ArrayAdapter` because you can't access the items list or override `GetItemId`.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, could you please provide me a simple example of a custom adapter implementing Filter? I cannot find an example that fits.

The parts needed are: 

1. The activity where the textbox is placed

2. The ORM Class that represents the Object from the DB

3. The adapter that should provide methods to use on the activity

Is there anything more? Thanks again!

Comment: You should look for tutorials on "custom adapter implementation" and "Android Filter implementation". If you need someone to write the code for you I'd suggest putting a bounty on you question, but that is possible only after you have a higher reputation on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need someone to write the code for me, I only need some information on how to build those adapters, but it seems that I'm the only one on the web trying to do such a thing...